# Git Pull with -m functionality

Tags: git

I'd like to run `git pull` in a script without breaking into the editor to ask for a comment.

Is this possible or do I need to do a `git fetch` and then `git merge -m`?

It seems there should be a way to pass the `-m` to merge.

Comment: If it's in a script, there's no difficulty involved in having it run `git fetch` first and then `git merge` (though it may be a bit slower on Windows I suppose—what I mean by "no difficulty" is you don't have to type extra commands...).

Comment: Agreed. I was just wondering if I was missing something about `pull`.

Answer (score 1):

If you what your changes to become on top of the `origin` branch history without merge you can first `fetch` and then `rebase` onto it:

1. `git checkout your-branch`
2. `git fetch origin/your-branch`
3. `git rebase origin/your-branch`

You can get more info here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

But if you want to keep the original sequence of your git history commits there's no other way than to merge `origin` branch into your local branch.

Comment: What you're describing sounds a lot like `git pull --rebase`.